# text splitting in R with strsplit() function

Tags: r, split

**How to split a text string in R using `strsplit`, then copy and paste to a column?**

I am trying to split a text string after import an excel file, with one more output, which is to paste the split onto a new column.

*Here is what I have so far:*

```
> column_1<-head(sample_file,n=10)
> column_1
# A tibble: 10 x 13
   Name         Last PxChg `Px%Chg`    Vol `Volm%Chg`  OInt `OI%Chg` IVM   `IV%Chg`   Ntnl
   <chr>       <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 TSLA US 1~   1.49 -0.31 -17.22   172122 34.24      46048 3.37     41.9~ 5.39     4.12e9
 2 TSLA US 1~   0.62 -0.23 -27.06   157765 31.17      30183 19.71    43.8~ 7.5      3.78e9
 3 TSLA US 1~   3.75 -0.95 -20.21   139902 68.69      14796 52.33    40.6~ 6.17     3.35e9
 4 TSLA US 1~   0.98 -0.27 -21.6    110129 120.77     21548 0.72     42.6~ 7.06     2.64e9
 5 TSLA US 1~   5.23 -0.87 -14.26    88546 200.2       3878 96.26    40.9~ 3.49     2.12e9
 6 AAPL US 1~   0.27 -0.45 -62.5     87678 -16.01000~ 26170 16.8     16.3~ 5.61     1.69e9
 7 TSLA US 0~ 209.   -2    -0.95     74870 143.56      2103 0        N.A.  N.A.     1.79e9
 8 TSLA US 1~   2.22 -0.43 -16.23    71601 15.07      10345 17.3999~ 41.3~ 5.93     1.71e9
 9 TSLA US 0~ 176.   -1.5  -0.84     69740 166.28      2090 0        N.A.  N.A.     1.67e9
10 AMC US 12~   0.02 -0.03 -60       68632 1371.53    69467 0.97     168.~ 2.76     4.66e7

> column_1[1]
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   Name                           
   <chr>                          
 1 TSLA US 12/08/23 C245 Equity   
 2 TSLA US 12/08/23 C250 Equity   
 3 TSLA US 12/08/23 P240 Equity   
 4 TSLA US 12/08/23 C247.5 Equity 
 5 TSLA US 12/08/23 P242.5 Equity 
 6 AAPL US 12/08/23 C195 Equity   
 7 TSLA US 01/19/24 P450 Equity   
 8 TSLA US 12/08/23 C242.5 Equity 
 9 TSLA US 01/19/24 P416.67 Equity
10 AMC US 12/08/23 C9 Equity
```

*By using `strsplit`, how do I get my desired output as shown below?*

[image: sample_file]

Basically what column A [Name] contains are stock symbol, expiry date, strike price and option type(Call/Put) and I would like to split column A by part and add to new columns as shown in the picture.

Thank you so much for ur help.

**Update**

By using the solutions below, here is what we have now:

```
sample_file<-separate(sample_file,Name,c('symbol','country','date','strike','type'),sep=' ')
```

[image]

However, when I am trying to seperate  or mutate option type in strike column, the below error msg is shown:

```
> sample_file<-mutate(option_type = gsub("\\d+|\\.", "", strike))
Error in is.factor(x) : object 'strike' not found
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to be minimally reproducible? The `name` column in the data you provided dont have any of the elements you describe in what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `strsplit` is the wrong tool here. Try `tidyr::separate` instead.

```r
tidyr::separate(df1, Name, c('symbol', 'country', 'date', 'code', 'type'), ' ')
#>    symbol country     date    code   type
#> 1    TSLA      US 12/08/23    C245 Equity
#> 2    TSLA      US 12/08/23    C250 Equity
#> 3    TSLA      US 12/08/23    P240 Equity
#> 4    TSLA      US 12/08/23  C247.5 Equity
#> 5    TSLA      US 12/08/23  P242.5 Equity
#> 6    AAPL      US 12/08/23    C195 Equity
#> 7    TSLA      US 01/19/24    P450 Equity
#> 8    TSLA      US 12/08/23  C242.5 Equity
#> 9    TSLA      US 01/19/24 P416.67 Equity
#> 10    AMC      US 12/08/23      C9 Equity
```

---

**Reproducible data taken from question**

```r
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c(
"TSLA US 12/08/23 C245 Equity", 
"TSLA US 12/08/23 C250 Equity", 
"TSLA US 12/08/23 P240 Equity", 
"TSLA US 12/08/23 C247.5 Equity", 
"TSLA US 12/08/23 P242.5 Equity", 
"AAPL US 12/08/23 C195 Equity", 
"TSLA US 01/19/24 P450 Equity", 
"TSLA US 12/08/23 C242.5 Equity", 
"TSLA US 01/19/24 P416.67 Equity", 
"AMC US 12/08/23 C9 Equity"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can separate using `separate_wider_delim`, and a few more `dplyr` options to get your exact desired output:

```
df %>% separate_wider_delim(Name, 
                            delim = " ",
                            names = c("stock", "country", "expiry", "strike_price", "equity"),
                            cols_remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(option_type = gsub("\\d+|\\.", "", strike_price)) %>%
  select(-c(country, equity))
```

Output:

```
#                               Name stock expiry   strike_price option_type
# 1     TSLA US 12/08/23 C245 Equity  TSLA 12/08/23         C245           C
# 2     TSLA US 12/08/23 C250 Equity  TSLA 12/08/23         C250           C
# 3     TSLA US 12/08/23 P240 Equity  TSLA 12/08/23         P240           P
# 4   TSLA US 12/08/23 C247.5 Equity  TSLA 12/08/23       C247.5           C
# 5   TSLA US 12/08/23 P242.5 Equity  TSLA 12/08/23       P242.5           P
# 6     AAPL US 12/08/23 C195 Equity  AAPL 12/08/23         C195           C
# 7     TSLA US 01/19/24 P450 Equity  TSLA 01/19/24         P450           P
# 8   TSLA US 12/08/23 C242.5 Equity  TSLA 12/08/23       C242.5           C
# 9  TSLA US 01/19/24 P416.67 Equity  TSLA 01/19/24      P416.67           P
# 10       AMC US 12/08/23 C9 Equity   AMC 12/08/23           C9           C
```

Answer (score 3):

### Base R

Typical `strsplit` + `do.call(rbind, args = _)` operation:

```r
> as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(df1$Name, " "))) |> 
  + `colnames<-`(c("symbol", "country", "date", "code", "type"))
   symbol country     date    code   type
1    TSLA      US 12/08/23    C245 Equity
2    TSLA      US 12/08/23    C250 Equity
3    TSLA      US 12/08/23    P240 Equity
4    TSLA      US 12/08/23  C247.5 Equity
5    TSLA      US 12/08/23  P242.5 Equity
6    AAPL      US 12/08/23    C195 Equity
7    TSLA      US 01/19/24    P450 Equity
8    TSLA      US 12/08/23  C242.5 Equity
9    TSLA      US 01/19/24 P416.67 Equity
10    AMC      US 12/08/23      C9 Equity
```

a few more

```r
x = strsplit(df1$Name, " ")
as.data.frame(Reduce(rbind, x), row.names = FALSE)
as.data.frame(t(list2DF(x)), row.names = FALSE) 
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(x), ncol = 5L, byrow = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's too obvious and I am missing something, but the error you are getting is because `strike` is not an object (that's what the message says), but `sample_file$strike` is. I would try piping the data frame as in the following:

```
sample_file <- sample_file %>%
    mutate(option_type = gsub("\\d+|\\.", "", strike))
```